# Stop at beginning of JavaScript code in Firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, breakpoints

When I first load a page in the Firefox debugger, no source files are shown, so it is not possible to set breakpoints until an error occurs (I don't want to have to insert "debugger;"). Is there a fast way to start running, stopping at the first executable JavaScript line? I tried Stepping In, which I thought should do this, but it does not do anything, probably because it only works when paused at a breakpoint.

I searched the Web and could not find any solution, even though this seems to me a common problem. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can load your page and once the file are present, set your breakpoints. Firefox should remember the breakpoint for the next run and stop at it. Alternativaly, the `debugger` keyword is a great way to achieve that even if you don't want to use it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I need to be able to breakpoint js that doesn't have an error. There is no way to set that initial breakpoint when the program runs without error. The debugger should do what I need without making me edit the program to add an error or the "debugger;" construct. Microsoft's C++ debuggers could do this. JavaScript debuggers should do this.